# filtering by one-digit number in MultiSelectField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have `MyModel`:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ELEMENTS_CHOICES = Choices(
        (1, 'element1'),
        (2, 'element2'),
        (3, 'element3'),
        (4, 'element4'),
        (10, 'element10'),
        (12, 'element12'),
    )
    elements = MultiSelectField(
        _('elements'),
        choices=ELEMENTS_CHOICES,
        blank=True,
    )
```

I have also some `MyModel` objects with `elements` values like below:

```
obj1.elements = ['1', '2', '3', '10', '12']
obj2.elements = ['1', '3', '10', '12']
obj3.elements = ['1', '3', '10']
obj4.elements = ['2']
```

How do I filter through this field values?

The filter I tried to use is:

```
search_id = 2
MyModel.objects.filter(elements_icontains=search_id)
```

It was ok before the two-digit numbers appeared in the `MyModel` field choices.
Now it returns `obj1`, `obj2` (because `12` is on the list, and it contains 2 as the part of it) and `obj4`.

I would like to search just for values with `2` number and get just `obj1` and `obj4` as results. Currently, the results are objects that contains `2` and `12`.

What is the right way to filter this field?

Comment: What is the database type you are using and why did chose to store it as delimited list in database, there are many drawbacks certainly regarding filtering performance
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: @iklinac postgres 9.4. The database structure was not my choice, I just try to fix this filter with no database changes.

Answer (score 1):

Storing data as comma-separated lists in the database is not a great technique and it is generally advised against doing so. Your use case itself implies that you are facing this problem. If it is feasible you should redesign your model schema (**Recommended**) and use a `ForeignKey` or a `ManyToManyField` to achieve your goal.

If it is unfortunately not possible to change this schema for some reason you can only resolve to using regex to query your database:

```
import re


search_id = 2
filter_term = r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(str(search_id)) # \b is word boundary in regex
MyModel.objects.filter(elements__iregex=filter_term)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should propose proper database normalization for this particular problem instead.

If you still find yourself as having to go without changing database you could do it two way filter [regex](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex) or even better  by using `string_to_array()` as it can be indexed

This will require you to [perform `raw()` query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) something in a line of

```
WHERE 2 = any(string_to_array(elements));
```

You can then add [Functional Index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/indexes-functional.html) for added performance benefit